# NaN result calculating distance

Tags: jquery, math

I have looked through here and Google, although not found a fix, this code below seemed like it would work. I am trying to get distance from two latitudes and longtitudes to use with a google map. I can get all standard ways to work on another server, ie google api's etc.
I cannot get 'dist' to calculate. On the server I'm using it's got issues with XML. I've spent hours on this and guessing it's a simple fix (brain fog playing a part)

test html

```
FROM<br>
<input id="lat1" type="text" value="">Latitude<br>
<input id="lon1" type="text" value="">Longitude<br>
TO<br>
<input id="lat2" type="text" value="">Latitude<br>
<input id="lon2" type="text" value="">Longitude<br>
<hr>
<input id="dist" type="text" value="">Distance<br>
<br>
<button id="calc">Calculate</button>
<br>
<div id="dist_text"></div>
<div id="lat1_text"></div>
<div id="lon1_text"></div>
<div id="lat2_text"></div>
<div id="lon2_text"></div>
<div id="radtheta_text"></div>
```

script

```
$('#calc').click(function()
{
    var lat1=$('#lat1').val();
    var lon1=$('#lon1').val();
    var lat2=$('#lat2').val();
    var lon2=$('#lon2').val();
    var dist='0';
    var unit = 'M';
    if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
        $('#dist').val('ERROR');
    }
    else {
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
        var theta = lon1-lon2;
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
// Edited to remove this below, incase anyone else finds it where i did.
        //var dist = lon1-lon2;
        if (dist > 1) {
            dist = 1;
        }
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
        if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
        //var dist2 = dist.toFixed(4);
        //return dist;
        $('#dist').val(dist.toFixed(4));        
        $('#dist_text').text('Distance: ' + dist);
        $('#lat1_text').text('Latitude 1: ' + lat1);
        $('#lon1_text').text('Longitude 1: ' + lon1);
        $('#lat2_text').text('Latitude 2: ' + lat1);
        $('#lon2_text').text('Longitude 2: ' + lon2);
        $('#radtheta_text').text('radtheta: ' + radtheta);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `var dist = lon1-lon2` line of code?

Comment: This was a peice of code with a formula that looked like it would work.

Comment: You have two `var dist = ` in a row.

Comment: Printing the return value of each assignment statement is a good way to pinpoint the source of the NaN very quickly.

Comment: At first glance, `Math.acos(dist)` could be the problem - you never check for `dist < -1`, which is the lower end of `acos`'s domain. Also check that `lon*` and `lat*` are numbers and not strings.